# Creating importable Python 3 package / module

Tags: python, module, package

I am having trouble creating an importable Python package/library/module or whatever the right nomenclature is. I am using Python 3.7

The file structure I am using is:

```
Python37//Lib//mypackage

mypackage
    __init__.py
    mypackage_.py
```

The code in `__init__.py` is:

```
from mypackage.mypackage_ import MyClass
```

The code in `mypackage_.py` is:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, myarg = None):
        self.myvar = myarg
```

And from my desktop I try running the following code:

```
import mypackage

x = MyClass(None)
```

But get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\importtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = MyClass(None)
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't put your module in python37 library. It's a bad practice. Rather just add your module path to pythonpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't imported the name `MyClass` into your current namespace. You've imported `mypackage`. To access anything within `mypackage`, you need to prefix the name with `mypackage.<Name>`

```
import mypackage

x = mypackage.MyClass(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rdas says, you need to prefix the name with `mypackage.<Name>`.

I don't recommend doing this, but you can wildcard import in order to make `x = MyClass(None)` work:

```
from mypackage import *
```

Now, everything from `mypackage` is imported and usable in the current namespace. However, you have to be careful with wildcard imports because they can create definition conflictions (if multiple modules have the same name for different things).